# selected option in select dissappears on reload

Tags: php

Once it loads in my page, if nothing has been saved in the DB table, all options are shown. As soon as i make a selection and reload the page, the selected option dissapears from the list and isn`t reloaded in the dropdown. Instead, it displays the next value which takes the place of the selected one.

if i check the SQL statement and the `$str`, it does load all the options except the one which is selected which is in `$getBris` (it has a value).

What could be causing my select to not display my selected option and instead removing it from the list?

*It specifically doesn`t work in IE8, wasn`t working in Firefox but now it does

```
<script src="validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<html>
<body onLoad="checkSecondValue();">
</body>
</html>
<?php
    //retrieve all the bris for the drop down
include '../../inc/database.php';
// ORDER BY RAND()

$res = BbqcDatabase::getInstance()->doQuery('SELECT * FROM T_TOURNOI_BRIS');
$str = "<select name='ddlBrisSelected' id='ddlBrisSelected' onChange='checkSecondValue()'>";

$getBris = $_GET['bris'];
$getBris = $getBris - 1;
print_r("bris is : "+ $getBris);


if($getBris == null)
{
    $str .= "<option value='' selected></option>";
}
else
{
$str .= "<option value='999'>Choisir un bris</option>";
}

$i = 0;

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    if($data['F_BRISID'] == $getBris)
    {
        $str .= "<option value='" . $data['F_BRISID'] . "' selected '>" . $data['F_BRISTITLE'] . "</option>";
    }
    else 
    {
        $str .= "<option value='" . $data['F_BRISID'] . "'>" . $data['F_BRISTITLE'] . "</option>";
    }
    $i++;
}

if($getBris == 12)
{
    $str .= "<option value=12 selected>Autre</option>";
}
else
{
    $str .= "<option value=12>Autre</option>";
}

$str .= "</select>";

echo $str;

if(is_numeric($bris))
{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('test');checkSecondValue();</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid. `<script>` cannot be outside of `<head>` or `<body>`. Also the code you pasted lacks a doctype definition.

Comment: I've done the modifications, nothing has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your browser's *View Source* feature to inspect the actual HTML you are generating (which is, in fact, the only see the browser ever sees). It looks like you're inserting random single quotes.

**Update:**

```
<option value='" . $data['F_BRISID'] . "' selected '>" . $data['F_BRISTITLE'] . "</option>"
```

... will render as:

```
<option value='blah' selected '>blah</option>
```

It's the only error I've cared to spot but an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) should find them all. Also, I recommend you use this syntax:

```
<option value="blah" selected="selected">blah</option>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it fixed it, but it works now! Why would the random single quotes cause that? Thanks

Comment: @David Machel - The HTML specs dictate how HTML must be rendered by the browser. If you don't follow the specs, the browser has to guess and there are no rules for that.

Answer (score 1):

A construct like this

```
if($getBris == 12)
{
    $str .= "<option value=12 selected>Autre</option>";
}
else
{
    $str .= "<option value=12>Autre</option>";
}
```

is highly wasteful of space and forces you to duplicate a big chunk of html whose only difference is the "selected" attribute. Why not do something like this:

```
$selected = ($getBris == 12) ? ' selected' : '';
$str .= "<option value=12{$selected}>Autre</option>";
```